# Non repeating complete list of partial recursive functions

Tags: computability

Is it possible to list all partial recursive functions such that every function appears only once in the enumeration. More precisely, does there exist (total) recursive function $f:\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ such that for any two different values $a,b \in \mathbb{N}$ (where $a\ne b$) the following two properties are satisfied:

(1) $\phi_{f(a)} \ne \phi_{f(b)}$ (the two functions on the left and right hand side aren't the same)

(2) For any possible partial recursive function $g:\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ there exists some value $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $g=\phi_{f(N)}$ (the two functions on the left and right hand side are the same)

$\phi_x$ denotes the function computed by the program corresponding to index $x$ (under a reasonable 1-1 correspondence between the collection of programs and $\mathbb{N}$).

Comment: "Non repeating complete list" rather than "unique listing" may better describe it.  Up to you.

Comment: This would require a zero-test for partial recursive functions, which in turn would require a solution to the halting problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is a total computable function with those properties. The existence was proved by Friedberg in 1958 using a priority argument.

> Friedberg, Richard M. “Three Theorems on Recursive Enumeration. I. Decomposition. II. Maximal Set. III. Enumeration Without Duplication.” The Journal of Symbolic Logic, vol. 23, no. 3, 1958, pp. 309–316. JSTOR [www.jstor.org/stable/2964290](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2964290).

These uniformly computable non-repeating enumerations are called *Friedberg numberings* in the literature.

Comment: Thanks, having a glance .... it seems that the last result there is exactly what I was asking. After posting this question, one other variant of this question also came to my mind. If we denote the set of partial recursive functions (1 input) as $P$ and the set of total recursive functions (1 input) as $R$ then does there exist a total computable function that enumerates (using indexes) every element of $P-R$ once and exactly once (original question was for $P$). Does that follow as a not-so-difficult corollary of the results/techniques in the paper (or is this question little different)?

Comment: The original article linked to in this answer is unfortunately spywalled, but a different (rather dense) two-page proof by M. Kummer (1990) is found at https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0304397590901414

Comment: @SSequence: The technique in the proof I linked to does extend directly to enumerating the non-total partial recursive functions without repetition.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Nice link .... sounds quite interesting that there are two different techniques for the same problem

Comment: @SSequence: The author I link to does credit Friedberg with a core idea in the proof, so "two different techniques" may be to oversell the difference. It's probably more of an incremental improvement -- though evidently enough of an improvement that TCS accepted the 1990 article.